# Adding an array to a collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

First off very new to Meteor so sorry if I'm asking the obvious here. I'm having trouble getting around this. I've looked through discover meteor,other peoples projects and googled quite a bit. I'm confused since in order to make the template reactive I will have to add the grid to a collection publish through server/ subscribe through client with Autodeps. I'm not sure how to add the grid to a collection I tried something like:

```
 Template.grid.buttons = function (){
    var list = []
    for(var i=1*Math.random(); i<64; i++){
      list.push({value: i})

    }
    //currentGame is the collection for the current game
    currentGame.insert(list)

    }

  Template.grid.events({
    'click .button': function(ev) {
      $(ev.target).css('visibility', 'hidden');
   }
});
```

This is where I'm getting confused I can't add the grid to a collection and update the changes of the buttons unless I'm using an autodeps.
**This is going to be a 2 player game the object of the game is to press as many buttons as you can before they're gone so when player 1 presses a button it disappears player 2 should also see the button disappear and not be able to click it. How do I add the buttons to a collection and make every change to the buttons (click and disappearing) appear to both users?**  If you want to see more of my code or see the game in real time:
 [GitHub](https://github.com/Yahkob/BubblePopper) and here is   [The actual meteor project link](http://testerthing.meteor.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection.insert is expecting an object with key-value pairs. Rather than sending it an array, revise your code like:

```
currentGame.insert({grid: list});
```

or even better:

```
// Define currentUser to be the player whose actions executed this code
currentGame.insert({player: currentUser, grid: list});
```